# How to NOT resolve symbolic links in NSOpenPanel?

Tags: objective-c, nsopenpanel

Whenever I select a path that includes a symbolic link, NSOpenPanel returns the resolved path. e.g.:

```
ln -s /Users/myuser/some/path/here /Users/myuser/mylink
```

Now I select the file `/Users/myuser/mylink/file.txt`, but `[[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0]` is `/Users/myuser/some/path/here/file.txt`.

How can I make NSOpenPanel to return what I selected (not to resolve the symlink)?

Answer (score 3):

Set `resolvesAliases` to `NO`:

```
NSOpenPanel *oPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
oPanel.resolvesAliases = NO;

if ([oPanel runModal] == NSOKButton) {
    NSLog([[[oPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0] absoluteString]);
}
```

Comment: This does not work. resolvesAliases nor setResolvesAliases:NO won't work, because the problem is with **symbolic links**, not aliases.

Comment: I think you didn't read my use case. I did not create a symlink to the leaf (file.txt), but a symlink within the path. In my example I created a symlink to a directory: `ln -s /Users/myuser/some/path/here /Users/myuser/mylink` and then I selected a file within that structure: `/Users/myuser/mylink/file.txt`.